# Parse Server curl GET command not working

Tags: curl, heroku, get, command-line-interface, parse-server

I've tried looking up Parse documents as well as look up existing questions on Stackoverflow but I wasn't able to find the answer. I am trying to return objects in class using the following curl command in the CLI. My Parse-Server app is deployed on Heroku.

```
curl -X GET \
 -H "X-Parse-Application-Id:xxxxxxxxxx”\
 -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key:xxxxxxxxxx” \
 -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
http://xxxxxxxxx.herokuapp.com/parse/classes/Random
```

I am expecting this command to return objects in "Random" class in json format, but all I am getting is (not even an error message):

```
>
```

I don't think there is anything wrong with the curl command above, but I would certainly appreciate any guidance.

Comment: use `-v` at the end of your curl command and see the debug output for any error.

Comment: Hi Sabuj, thanks for your comment. I added **-v** at the end of the curl command and I'm still getting just a **>** where the output should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put it all on one line and see if you still encounter that issue